# Returning an Object after setting another property in a single line

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there a way I could write the below code within the method in a single line, there is no issue with the code but just curious

```
public MyObject getObj(String name){
  MyObj myObj = PoolInstance.get(name);
  myObj.setFound(true);
  return myObj;
}
```

For some reason I cannot modify the PoolInstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may encapsulate the logic in setter that returns the object's instance itself:

```
class MyObject {

    private boolean found;

    public MyObject withFound(boolean isFound) {
        this.found = isFound;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public MyObject getObj(String name){
   return PoolInstance.get(name).withFound(true);
}
```

Also consider using GoF `Builder` design pattern for more idiomatic and flexible code: [Builder pattern example with explanation](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer NO,

Reason :

The first intuition would be to

```
return PoolInstance.get(name).setFound(true);
```

but that's **not** correct since setFound does not return MyObj.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with stream though not so readable. It looks like:

```
public MyObject getObj(String name){
    return Stream.of(PoolInstance.get(name)).peek(o -> o.setFound(true)).findFirst().get();
}
```